# Reduce specific cubic equation to quadratic

Tags: cubics

Please help, equation $3x-x^3=1$ has three roots. Interesting fact that $|x_3|= x_1+x_2$. Is it possible to reduce this equation to a quadratic?

Comment: `Interesting fact that ...` Not too surprising since $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ by Vieta's formulas.

Comment: "reduce this equation to a quadratic": what do you mean exactly ? Cubics can be solved in closed-form in all cases.

Comment: Basically I attempt to find purely geometric solution to 3x-x^3=h, where 2<h<0. Geometrically simple relations between roots suggest possibility without involvement of cubic curves.

Comment: mistake (typo ) 2>h>0

Answer (score 1):

What we can do is use the root coefficient relationships to express any two roots of the cubic equation in terms of the third root.  Let the cubic equation be $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ and let $r$ be any root.  Then the remaining two roots must sum to $-(ra+b)/a$ and their product must be $-d/(ra)$ leading to the quadratic equation:

$(ra)x^2+(r^2a+rb)x-d=0$

and the other two roots are:

$r_{\pm} = \frac{-(r^2a+rb)\pm \sqrt{(r^2a+rb)^2+4rad}}{2ra}$

In some applications, such as the thermodynamics problem of modeling vapor liquid equilibrium with a cubic equation of state, we can set up cubic equations to have a predefined root (corresponding to one phase in the equilibrium problem) and use the above scheme to get the other roots.

Comment: Awesome! Empirically  I found that 1/r1 = r3-1, 1/r2 = 1-r1 and 1/r3 = r2-1. But solution you provided give much more general relations between roots!

Comment: Never would think that this observation can assist to improve prediction of phase change of state of matter. Mathematical modeling seem to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

No, because our equation has three roots.

If you mean if is it possible to write

this equation in the form $(x-a)(x^2+bx+c)=0$, where $\{a,b,c\}\subset\mathbb Q$,

then it's impossible again because our equation has no rational roots.

Comment: Useless, but not impossible. Indeed if one of the roots of the given equation $3x-x^3=1$ is $a$ then it is possible to write the equation as $(x-a)(x^2+bx+c)=0$

Comment: @Raffaele We can not do it over $\mathbb Q$.